# Safari notifications

Tags: safari, notifications

I've disabled prompts for notifications in Safari but still get them. What do I do? I've got the latest macOS version with all the updates.

### Update #1 some screenshots

[image: the prompt]
[image: settings]

Comment: Is the issue the notifications still come through, or the prompt for notifications. Some websites display their own banners which look like a web browser but aren't part of it. Do you have any screen shots or additional information you can show us.

Comment: It's regular Safari notifications (even work is frozen until I decide what to do

Comment: Again can you please share some more information like screenshots so we have some context to what you are talking about, it's not very clear at all.

Comment: Done. Don't think that it reveals much

Comment: Actually it was, because I thought you were talking about something else... possible answer in a mo.

Comment: Not sure that I understand you. What do you mean mo?

Comment: mo(ment), see answer below...

Answer (score 2):

So you've done everything correctly but the notifications are still coming through, there are a couple things to try...

But first please quit Safari, and then do a full reboot, and test again, as even when you close Safari the Safari notification service continues to run in the background.

If you are still having an issue:

1. Quit Safari.
2. Go to Finder.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
4. Type `~/Library/Preferences` into the field.
5. Press Go.
6. Find `com.apple.Safari`.
7. Move it somewhere safe.
8. Reopen Safari and reconfigure the `Allow websites to ask permission to send push notifications`.
9. Try with one of the problem websites.

*This will remove your Safari preferences and will need to be setup again but it may resolve the issue.*